# Find file size before downloading Image with Scraper wget

Tags: unix, wget

I am trying to get an image/video size before my wget actually downloads it. is there a way to get the size and save it to a variable?

I tried to find this online, however, I was unable to find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--spider` option and then save the output to a text file:

```
$ wget --spider https://www.google.com/image.jpg > output.txt
$ wget --spider https://www.google.com/video.mp4 > output.txt
```

Example output:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2016-09-16 14:23:42--  http://www.bbc.co.uk/
Resolving www.bbc.co.uk (www.bbc.co.uk)... 212.58.244.67, 212.58.246.91
Connecting to www.bbc.co.uk (www.bbc.co.uk)|212.58.244.67|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  ...
Length: 171933 (168K) [text/html]  <---------- Right here is the file size
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Then using `awk` to read the 2nd word of the 10th line to get the file size:

```
$ awk 'fileSize==10 {print $2}' output.txt
```